# Laravel, Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, eloquent

I am following the instructions from the Laravel Documentation but I can't seem to make the rule work. Basically, I want to add a unique rule for both *email* and *username* fields for updating the user profile, but it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something?

Here is the function for updating user credentials

```
public function updateCredentials(Request $request, User $user)
{
    Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'username' => [
            'required','string','min:4','max:255',
            Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
        ],
        'email' => [
            'required','string','email','max:255', 
            Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
        ],
        'asdf' => 'required',
        'type' => 'required',
    ])->validate();
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you add `users` table structure in your question?

Comment: Nevermind, my mistake was wrong route model binding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update user profile,without changing his id,you dont need to set specific rule for that.
Without explicitly setting the new user id,it should stay the same.

You can just name the data you want to change like this:

```
    $user->name = request('name');
    $user->lastname  = request ('lastname);
    $user->email = request('email');
    ...
    $user->save();

    session()->flash('message','Profile update complete!');

    return redirect('/home');
```

Doing this the data you want will update,but the id will stay the same.

Comment: No, I am not asking for the ID to be changed. I want the unique rule for validating the email and username field but ignoring the current user who have the email and username set.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be some bug.

Adding filed name worked for me:

```
Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id, 'users')
```